# is there a way to structure truely hierarchical project and/or modules in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

With larger build systems I have set up a hierarchy of items where one item may contain sub items and so on.

So one can lets say import module 2 and it would contain modules 3,4, and 5 so an application that includes module 2 will automatically "include" 3,4 and 5.

This so the "whole mess" is "refactorable" "recompilable" etc.

But then if one makes changes "inside" module 2 ie adds a new dependency to module 2 or adds "artifacts" or whatever they are then inherited by anything that assigns module 2 as a dependency.

In a certain sense this would be like having a "project" included inside another "project" as a dependency, so the whole mess can be treated as a "megga" project.

?????

Comment: Maven is your answer.

Comment: I have a ruby based system and yes doing this outside intelliJ is the answer that isn't an answer :)   I can't stand using ant or it's derivatives as a "programming" system. :)

Comment: Totally agree with Andrew Finnell. In fact I thought you were describing a multi module maven project until I read Andrew's comment :). Would using jRuby and it's maven integration be an option ?

Comment: I of course don't know enough about Maven to fully comment :) I Have read the wikipedia page and the beginning of the apache documentation.